# Merge similar columns and add extracted values to dict

Tags: pandas

Given this input:

```
pd.DataFrame({'C1': [6, np.NaN, 16, np.NaN], 'C2': [17, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN],
             'D1': [8, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6], 'D2': [15, np.NaN, np.NaN, 12]}, index=[1,1,2,2])
```

I'd like to combine columns beginning in the same letter (the Cs and Ds), as well as rows with same index (1 and 2), and extract the non-null  values to the simplest representation without duplicates, which I think is something like:

```
{1: {'C': [6.0, 17.0], 'D': [8.0, 15.0]}, 2: {'C': [16.0, 1.0], 'D': [6.0, 12.0]}}
```

Using `stack` or `groupby` gets me part of the way there, but I feel like there is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename `columns` by lambda function for first letters with aggregate `list`s after [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then create nested `dictionary` in dict comprehension:

```
s = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[0]).stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list)

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{1: {'C': [6.0, 17.0], 'D': [8.0, 15.0]}, 2: {'C': [16.0, 1.0], 'D': [6.0, 12.0]}}
```